# I forgot where i created my bitcoin wallet

Tags: wallet, e-wallet, websites

I have a wallet that contains bitcoin, but I forgot on the site where I made the wallet. anybody know how to find which website location that create my wallet ?
do i need to write the wallet address here?

Comment: the sites where you can get bitcoins come and go. There is no way for us to estimate... The wallet address does not help, only the private keys or a seed would help.

Comment: do you have your private key ?

Comment: How can i find my bitcoin. As look in history and I change my phone. And I think the company my have been shut down. Does this mean I lost it.???

Comment: Hi Kathleen, yes, if the entity that is keeping your coins in custody for you has disappeared your coins are likely inaccessible to you. If you were keeping your own private keys in software and removed the software without a backup, likely the same. In the future, please start a new topic when you have a question.

Comment: I had a similar problem could not find the website that hosted my wallet, I went to google search history ( not the browser history but the history that google search has) and started to research about the time I created my wallet, visited the sites I visited back then, and found the wallet.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet might just be to look at your browser's history and use the search box to find which site you visited to create your wallet.

Answer (score 2):

Search through your email history as you will have had to verify your account at some point.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answer, i am looking my browser history one by one and finally find the website where i created the wallet address..
Best Regards